# Displaying spinner waiting indicator while loading web page

Tags: wpf, webbrowser-control

I have a WPF application that is loading web pages.
Some of the web pages taking long time.
I want to display an indicator like spinner
I have the spinner already and using it in other places of the WPF using the storyboard animation of the WPF.
The question is, can I use it in the web browser control?
Can you let the web browser control load in different thread than the UI thread?
Should I use Frame control or web browser control?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use a Frame and handle the LoadCompleted event.  In other words, show the spinner until LoadCompleted fires.

There is no need to use a separate thread for loading:  The Frame control already provides for loading the content in the background.